# Client socket hangs on response

Tags: java, php, android, sockets, tcp

I have simple TCP server in java.

```
// while(true), try catch etc.
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
message = bufferedReader.readLine();

OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bw.write("test");
bw.flush();


inputStreamReader.close();
clientSocket.close();
bufferedReader.close();
os.close();
osw.close();
```

and I build the client in PHP, but it hangs on getting response, when I build the same simple client in Java it works well. How to solve this problem?

PHP Client:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

$message = 'test';


$status = socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), MSG_EOF, $address, $port);
if($status !== FALSE) {
    $message = '';
    $next = '';

    while ($next = socket_read($socket, 1)) {
        $message .= $next;
    }

    var_dump($message);
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}

socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solve to this problem.

When i am sending message i must to do "\n" on the end of the string. I don't know why. Maybe anyone know why?